# Prove $f : A\rightarrow B, g: B\rightarrow C$ , and $g\circ f: A \overset{1-1}{\rightarrow}C$, then $g:B\overset{1-1}{\rightarrow}C$

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I am completely stuck on this, I want to say it's true and do a proof by contrapositive, since if g is not surjective, then $\exists b \in B $ such that for $c \in C, f(b)\neq f(c)$, but I'm not sure where to go with this.

Thanks!

Comment: The "1-1" means injective or bijective? This is a why using the Bourbaki's terminology is preferable.

Comment: @Gudson Chou It doesn't matter it is still false. Let $A=C=\{1\}$, $B=\{1,2\}$, $f$ be the inclusion and $g$ the unique map.

Comment: I think we just have $g$ is injective.

Comment: @Nex That is correct. I was just trying to imply the terminology matter.

Answer (score 1):

It's false in general, though it's true if $f$ is a surjection onto $B$.
A counterexample when $f$ is not surjective:

$A = B = \{0\}, C=\{0,1\}$, $f(0) = 0$, and $g(x)=0$ for $x=0,1$.